# How to post data grid devextreme to controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, html, devextreme

i have using datagrid with devextreme.
how can i send datagrid to controller in asp.net mvc?
i have tried this in my view :

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("action-name", "controller-name", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div id="frm"></div>
                <div id="grid"></div>
                <div class="submit-button" id="submitBtn"></div>
            }
```

and this is my model:

```
public class class-name
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; set; }
    }

 public class ContactInfo
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

in my contoller i get my form data(class-name) but the grid data(ContactInfo) is null

Comment: Do you use editing in a grid? Could you provide your data grid options? And one more important thing, what DevExtreme version do you use?

Comment: I using 16.2 version. and yes i have adding,updating and deleting the rows. but how can i send all data in datagrid in array to my controller when i click on button, like when i click submit button and the form data will send to my controller.

Answer (score 3):

In your case you can use [ASP.NET MVC Wrappers for DevExtreme](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/Guide/ASP.NET_MVC_Wrappers/Fundamentals/). In that case you will be able to bind a grid to WebApi controller like this:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid()
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .WebApi()
        .Controller("GridData")
        .Key("OrderID")
        .LoadAction("GetAllOrders")
        .InsertAction("InsertOrder")
        .UpdateAction("UpdateOrder")
        .DeleteAction("RemoveOrder")
    )
)
```

And the controller:

```
 public class DataGridWebApiController : ApiController {

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAllOrders(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions) {
        //...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage InsertOrder(FormDataCollection form) {
        //...
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateOrder(FormDataCollection form) {
        //...
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public void RemoveOrder(FormDataCollection form) {
        //...
    }
 }
```

Well, it isn't necessary to send all datagrid data to a server side. Just manage only updated data.

There is an additional information about a data binding in [this article](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/Guide/ASP.NET_MVC_Wrappers/Data_Binding/#ASPNET_Web_API).

Take a look at [this demo](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Data_Grid/WebAPIService/Mvc/Light/) as well.

Comment: thats great! but how can i post data(both my form and grid data) to my controller when i click on submit menu . i tried onclick method button and use ajax in it but i didnt successful.

Comment: Why do you want to post all data grid to a server side? It sounds a bit strange. You can process data changing using built-in dxDataGrid functionality. I mean implement controllers for CRUD operations and enable editing for datagrid. Like in the sample above.

Comment: leman17 wants to save changed grid data together with other data on his form together in one single form POST submit. I wonder how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 3):

you can use a cellTemplate for every column and in cellTemplate you have to use **hidden input**. for example assume this code:

```
factory.Add().DataField("Mobile")
             .CellTemplate(@<text>
              <%= text %>
              <input type='hidden' name='Addresses[<%= rowIndex %>].Mobile' value='<%= value %>' />
              </text>);
```

text,rowIndex,value is DevExtreme object. 
for more info please check the **cellInfo** section of link.
https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/?search=columns

Comment: Please add some context around Links, copy relevant parts and paste them alongside it in case the site content changes or becomes unavailable.

Comment: Is this still the only valid solution?

Comment: @Sven if your grid has one page or server operation is false you can use getDataSource() instead. for example: var allGridData=$("#yourGridId").dxDataGrid('instance').getDataSource();

Comment: Hi Mostafa, thanks. My scenario is slightly different: I want to post selected rows only in a TreeList control bound to local data.

Answer (score -1):

for my question i found my way .
here is solution .
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T489645
thanks to devextreme support.

Comment: "You can't view this ticket. Log in if this is your ticket." It's better to quote and attribute the text in your answer in case the page becomes inaccessible as this one has.